# Inject CSS in firefox add on sdk

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox-addon-sdk

I failed to inject CSS in firefox extension. Here is my code.

```
var tbb = require('toolbarbutton').ToolbarButton({
  id: 'button',
  label: 'us-button',
  image: self.data.url('img/on.png'),
  onCommand: function () {

    tabs.activeTab.attach ({

        contentScriptFile: [
            self.data.url('jquery/jquery.min.js'),
            self.data.url('jquery/jquery-ui.js'),
            self.data.url('recuperation.js'),
            self.data.url('dialog.js')
      ],
      contentStyleFile: self.data.url('jquery/jquery-ui.css'),
```

I use [toolbar buttons](https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib) by Erik Vold. 
contentStyleFile doesn't seem to work. When I click to the button, the JQuery dialog appears but without the css file.

Comment: Question: why *should* it work? The [documentation on `tab.attach()`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html#attach%28options%29) doesn't mention any `contentStyleFile` option.

Comment: So, how to call JQuery library when I click to a toolbar button ? I just want to make a simple JQuery dialog window visible.

Comment: Use your content script to inject a style tag into the document?

Comment: I use JQuery: $(#id).css({...}); to inject CSS. However it takes time to convert JQuery-ui.css in my content script. Can we find other means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get away with using a `PageMod` which would bring in the style sheet you want and can also inject the JavaScript.

Something like this could work:

```
var pm = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
  include: tabs.activeTab.url,
  attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
  contentScriptFile: [
    self.data.url('jquery/jquery.min.js'),
    self.data.url('jquery/jquery-ui.js'),
    self.data.url('recuperation.js'),
    self.data.url('dialog.js')
  ],
  contentStyleFile: self.data.url('jquery/jquery-ui.css')
});
```

Then later you'll want to destroy this PageMod when you're done with it so they aren't just hanging around attached to old pages.

```
pm.destroy();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I put `include: tabs.activeTab.url,`, it doesn't work. I already have `var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');`. If I write `include: '*'`, it works. However, it's possible to call pageMod when I click to a button ?

Comment: You need to add `attachTo: ["existing", "top"],` to the PageMod options you pass otherwise it will wait until you reload the page.

Comment: Thank you. It works but only on the first tab that has been open, that's why I search a way to call pageMod when I press a button in the toolbar.

Comment: Just insert that pageMod code above into the `onCommand` function you have in your original post.  It will create a new pageMod each time the button is clicked for the activeTab at the time.  Ideally you'd actually just alter the include property instead of creating new pageMods.